# Doing navigation, while avoiding some region

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using navigation stack with PR2 and turtlebot in a simulated home environment. Is it possible to constrain the path of the robot so that it can avoid some region. For example, say floor of the room has white tiles with few red tiles at center, and I want the robot, not to run over the red tiles. Or say there is some marking or carpeting on the path (having different color), and I need the robot to do navigation only on that path.

Any suggestion or pointers on how I can achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

I needed this for executing action for a command like : "Move to the chair, avoiding the red region."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52289/doing-navigation,-while-avoiding-some-region/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would have to write a custom Cost function depending on your particular need!!
In your case when you said that you wanted to avoid red tiles you certainly would term them as obstacles in your code..and then run a suitable path planner..

---

Originally posted by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) with karma: 263 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-01-15**:
Hi Karan,
Thanks for the reply. Is there any tutorial etc., on writing the custom cost function. Or can you please point me to specific file where I need to make the changes in. In my case the cost function will change depending on the command (and that is exactly what I want to do.)
Thanks

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-15**:
You would have to write a node yourself which would process the input image stream and mark the regions which turn out to be red. Then make a 2d grid of surrounding region which has those regions marked to be non traversable. Then run a suitable planner..